# How to set environment variable on heroku on just workers?

Tags: heroku

I would like to be able to adjust some environment variables on Heroku without making my whole web application restart since they are just applicable to code run on the workers.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, setting a config var on an application restarts the whole application, you cannot set vars just for an individual process type.